# Firebase connection with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Could not find method android() for arguments [flutter_buq5m2qolwfcdoan8iv26i0vo$_run_closure1@139b04eb] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

File Location :- Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 80

When I connect My App with Firebase.

After follow all the instruction of the official Site of Firebase.com

Why would my project can't connect to Firebase?

Is there anyone have solution??

Comment: Did you install dependencies using flutterfire_cli?

Comment: No, I Install firebase_auth dependency using flutter pub get.

Comment: Did you install firebase_core dependency

Comment: Yes, I installed both firebase_auth & firebase_core dependencies.